# Append image to document in C# before document.close()

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I create a document from a HTML page, then save it as a PDF.

Before closing the document, I need to add a PNG to the end of the document.

The PNG file is a siganture.

**Declaration of my document**

```
// Create a Document object
var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);

// Create a new PdfWriter object, specifying the output stream
var output = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("MyFirstPDF.pdf"), FileMode.Create);
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

// Open the Document for writing
document.Open();
```

**Write HTML page**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
base.Render(hWriter);
```

**Add elements to document and close. This is where I want to attach a png (local to server) to the document before closing (and generating the pdf).**

```
string imgFileName = "signature" + ".png";
string outputFilePath = ConfigHelper.GetImageOutputFullPath(imgFileName);

var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(PageResultCleaned), null);

// Enumerate the elements, adding each one to the Document...
foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
    document.Add(htmlElement as IElement);

// Close the Document - this saves the document contents to the output stream
document.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the image as an img element to the HTML before adding the HTML to the document.

```
PageResultCleaned = PageResultCleaned.Replace(@"<h3>Sign Here:</h3>", "<img src=\"" + outputFilePath + "\" alt=\"Signature\" height=\"100\" width=\"300\">");
```